# Helm chart upgrade with different Docker image tag

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a question about a Helm upgrade. I'm working on a helm chart which deploys a pod with a docker image tag:2.190.1-alpine.
Release name is jenkins.
I want change the docker image in the helm chart to 2.240
I launch:

`helm upgrade jenkins codecentric/jenkins --set image.tag=2.2`

But I got error:

`Error: UPGRADE FAILED: unable to decode "": resource.metadataOnlyObject.ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta.Labels: ReadString: expects " or n, but found 2, error found in #10 byte of ...|version":2.240,"helm.|..., bigger context ...|s.io/name":"jenkins","app.kubernetes.io/version":2.240,"helm.sh/chart":"jenkins-1.7.0"},"name":"myReleases|...`

Has anyone had experience with this?

Here is a deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  creationTimestamp: "2020-02-06T22:39:51Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: master
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: jenkins
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: jenkins
    helm.sh/chart: jenkins-1.5.1
  name: jenkins
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "28697012"
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/jenkins
  uid: 9934dea3-b3a1-4109-b725-da5410aacc5f
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: master
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: jenkins
      app.kubernetes.io/name: jenkins
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/init: e43addd28e27d8ab36052943e5586515d252a27c3ddd85e15c43e99501ab1c0b
        checksum/ref: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: master
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: jenkins
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/name: jenkins
        helm.sh/chart: jenkins-1.5.1
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT
          value: "50000"
        - name: JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Dhudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.initialDelay=0 -Dhudson.model.LoadStatistics.decay=0.7
            -Dhudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.MARGIN=30 -Dhudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.MARGIN0=0.6
            -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=2
            -XshowSettings:vm
        image: jenkins/jenkins:2.190.1-alpine
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /login
            port: http
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 90
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: jenkins-master
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 50000
          name: agent
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /login
            port: http
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
          name: jenkins-home
        - mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins
          name: jenkins-plugins
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      initContainers:
      - args:
        - jenkins/jenkins
        - 2.190.1-alpine
        - "false"
        command:
        - /init/init.sh
        image: jenkins/jenkins:2.190.1-alpine
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: jenkins-init
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /init
          name: init
        - mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
          name: jenkins-home
        - mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins
          name: jenkins-plugins
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 1000
      serviceAccount: default
      serviceAccountName: default
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: jenkins-home
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: jenkins-pvc
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: jenkins-plugins
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 365
          name: jenkins-init
        name: init
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2020-02-06T22:39:51Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2020-02-06T22:40:32Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "jenkins-866f548f55" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  - lastTransitionTime: "2020-06-05T12:13:56Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2020-06-05T12:13:56Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  observedGeneration: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

Is it safe to edit deployment file directly? 
I noticed that the ERROR code listed version chart 1.7.0 even though mine is 1.5.1. Maybe I should state in the upgrade command that I stay with the old version?

Comment: can you show your pod template file

Comment: @edbighead I install heml chart using 
`helm install myReleases  repo/chart`
I can show pod or deployment file Igenerated on the Kubernetes.
Is that what you need to see?

Comment: Yes, a deployment

Comment: I edited question with deployment and with a few more thoughts.

Comment: I think main problem is that you are trying to edit already fully rendered deployment. Editing a deployment from templates folder generated for example from `helm create mychart` should be fine

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by defining a version of the chart in the upgrade command
`helm upgrade jenkins codecentric/jenkins --set image.tag=2.240 --version 1.5.1`

Comment: Thank you @edbighead for your time and suggestions